# logback error after upgrading springboot and java to latest version

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, slf4j

After upgrading springboot to 3.0.7 version and java to 17 in the project, following error started appearing, though the project is working fine before the upgrade.

```
Logging system failed to initialize using configuration from 'null'
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Missing attribute [name] in element [appender] near line 43
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender[LOGSTASH] - No attached appenders found.
```

I tried many ways to include and exclude slf4j/log4j dependencies but the issue persists.

Comment: It is very difficult to help you without any related information. Do you have a lot of dependencies in your build script? Can you try to find any .xml file in your project and dependencies to see the `line 43`?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. To solve the problem, just set the "name"-Tag for your appender in the resources/logback.xml. (line 43) There might be something like

```
<appender class="...">
```

I still don't understand what exactly changed in Spring and Logback making the name required